# How to pass query string and POST params in grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am using [`grape`](https://github.com/intridea/grape) `Restful API`. I want to create a post method with `POST` parameters and Query string parameters. How to use them?  Can anybody give me a nice example?

I know to pass Query string params(key, sign) as follows. but how to use POST params. I want to pass post params (say name,id). How to do that in code.

https://www.abc.com/api/v2/list?key=abc&sign=xyz

I have my code as follows

```
  post :new_user do
    key = params[:key]
    sign = params[:sign]
    HTTParty.post("https://www.abc.com/api/v2/list?key=abc&sign=xyz")
  end
```

In addition to that I want to pass post params (say name,id). how to do that?

Comment: In the example you give, `val_1` and `val_2` _are_ query-string parameters. Your question is, How do you pass parameter values in _both_ the query string ("GET-style") _and_ the request body ("POST-style") simultaneously, is that right?

Comment: @SimonSouth - correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post and query string parameters rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360072/post-and-query-string-parameters-rails)